# how can we unlock the database in django?

Tags: sqlite

Chrome history is stored in the Sqlite3 database in Ubuntu, while I am trying to access the browser history I am getting this following error

```
rural@admin:~$ Sqllite3 ~/. config /chromium/Default/History
could not get list of tables: 5, database is locked
```

Any help can be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: what has this got to do with django or python?

Comment: i want to get the complete browser history of the user,so we need it

Comment: there is absolutely nothing at all in this question to show that django or python are being used.

Comment: Ok but how can we unlock the database in django

Comment: Just close Chrome.